# Does there exist a continuous onto function $f:[0,1] \to (0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If there is, what's an example. If not, how do I prove none exists?

Comment: Hint: A continuous function $f: [0,1]\to (0,1)$ must attains it's maximum as $[0,1]$ is closed and bounded.

Comment: The image of $f$ is doomed to be compact.

Comment: Without compactness you can argue that the inverse image of an open set is open.

Comment: @hjhjhj57 That doesn't work. The closed interval $[0,1]$ *is* open in the subspace topology.

Comment: @MikeHaskel You're right, thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. The continuous image of a compact set is compact.